ViroVideo for ViroReact only plays audio but never video
I am new to using ViroReact: https://viro-community.readme.io/docs/overview
I want to make an AR app.  But I don't know how to get the video of the <ViroVideo> element to display: https://viro-community.readme.io/docs/virovideo
The <ViroVideo> seems to only be able to play audio.  Here's the code for my App.tsx:
import {
  ViroARScene,
  ViroARSceneNavigator,
  ViroTrackingReason,
  ViroTrackingStateConstants,
  ViroVideo,
  ViroARTrackingTargets,
  ViroARImageMarker
} from "@reactvision/react-viro";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

ViroARTrackingTargets.createTargets({
  "birdImage": {
    source: require("./assets/mural/bird.jpg"),
    orientation: "Up",
    physicalWidth: 0.25 // in meters
  }
});

const HelloWorldSceneAR = () => {
  function onInitialized(state: any, reason: ViroTrackingReason) {
    console.log("onInitialized", state, reason);
    if (state === ViroTrackingStateConstants.TRACKING_NORMAL) {
    } else if (state === ViroTrackingStateConstants.TRACKING_UNAVAILABLE) {
      console.log("Not found");
    }
  }

  function onFound(item) {
    console.log("FOUND " + item);
  }

  return (
    <ViroARScene onTrackingUpdated={onInitialized}>
      <ViroARImageMarker
        target={"birdImage"}
        onAnchorFound={()=>onFound("BIRD")}
      >
        <ViroVideo
          source={require('./assets/mp4/movie-file.mp4')}
          loop={true}
          position={[1,2,-3]}
          scale={[0.2, 0.2, 0.2]}
         />
      </ViroARImageMarker>
    </ViroARScene>
  );
};

export default () => {
  return (
    <ViroARSceneNavigator
      autofocus={true}
      initialScene={{
        scene: HelloWorldSceneAR,
      }}
      style={styles.f1}
    />
  );
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  f1: { flex: 1 },
  helloWorldTextStyle: {
    fontFamily: "Arial",
    fontSize: 30,
    color: "#ff0000",
    textAlignVertical: "center",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});


When I run npm start, this app gets loaded onto my Android phone. THen when I point my phone's camera at ./assets/mural/bird.jpg, the my phone plays the AUDIO of the ./assets/mp4/movie-file.mp4.  But no VISUAL is ever displayed.  I tried random values for position= and scale= for the <ViroVideo> tag, but the result is always the same: only the audio is heard and no video is displayed.
How do I show a video with <ViroVideo>?
